# Disable hiding of the mouse cursor in Word 2013 when typing

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word, mouse, microsoft-office-2013

Whenever I start typing, the mouse cursor disappears in Word 2013 on Windows 10. I understand that this is a *feature*, but it's incredibly annoying.

I went trough the options in Word but couldn't find any related setting. I've disabled the `Hide pointer while typing` option in Windows.

Is there any way to disable this *feature*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click the "Start" menu, select "Control Panel" and click to open the "Mouse" option. Select the "Pointer Options" tab and check for the "Hide pointer while typing" option in the Visibility section. Click the box to de-select it if it's selected.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The "Hide pointer while typing" is already unchecked. But still Word itself hide the pointer when typing. 5K views on this question shows how bad this feature is. Microsoft sucks.